# What mouse model do I need to not have double click problem in LP:365300?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, mouse

I'm experiencing a problem with my mouse model  Logitech B110. I looked on the internet and found that certain mouse models does have a problem in ubuntu 11.10 and now in 12.04. My mouse is one of them.

I usually experience this bug: I click once (doesn't matter which button), but got double click instead. According to what I found on the internet this somehow tied with amount of electrical current that is generated by mouse as a response to click and this problem hardly will be addressed in ubuntu in the near future. So I would like to have a list of 'officially' or not 'officially' mouses that don't have such problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a bug in launchpad for this issue (LP [#365300](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/365300)). Comment [#55](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/365300/comments/55) points out that this is in fact a hardware issue among all sold mice in the market. It seems that Microsoft fixes this by implementing the double click delay in reverse I think. If you experience this issue try another mouse, that should solve it.

Comment: "hardware issue among all sold mice in the market" oh come on. This is a total nonsense. Why then "all sold mice" works perfectly in windows? Next they'll say that it's a bug in all users born after 1950. Thanks for your answer, but the problem is I can't buy the whole range of mices to check them. So, I hoped that Ubuntu authors tested at least some of them and made a compatible mice list. Unfortunately, it seems they thinking its a bug in a hardware. Great.

Comment: You probably got it wrong. All I said was, this could happen with every mouse and while being a very rare case nobody implemented countermeasures. If the cause is a hardware issue that does not occur with a mouse of the same model and make one usually replaces the faulty product with a new one. I never experienced this by myself, probably because I use wireless mice, but I see no point in telling people to get the most expensive mouse in the market or only buy mice from a certain brand to theoretically rule out an issue that users seldomly experience.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. But actually I tried a couple of mice of the same model, all have this problem. Maybe I'm just unlucky.

Comment: Have you reported a bug for this issue?

Comment: Yes I did. But I don't see any movement there.

Comment: Which bug is it?

Answer (score 1):

I have two Genius mouses (NetScroll 120 and Traveller 6000) and never had that problem.

Good Luck